# Android BLE send and recieve data in background

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am connected to an android BLE device and I am able to read and write data. In my scenario I have to keep reading data from the device and send response to the sent request. I was implementing on the main thread and after a while when it goes to Pause state the process would end. 
Do I have to use a Service class to read and write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The best approach is to use a Service class in Android since your Activity should not be responsible for any background operations such as performing any BLE read/write actions. You just have to bind your Service class with your Activity class.

Comment: Thanks, I have a BluetoothLeService Class that calls the write and read opertaions on the Gatt but how do I make it to run in background. I have a Braocast receiver in my activity that is receiving packets from the service class and on receiving I am sending a write operation.